Let $E$ be an extension of $F$ and let $A = \{e \in E: e$ is algebraic over $F\}$. Show that $A$ is a subfield of $E$ containing $F$.
Let $E$ be an extension of $F$ and let $A = \{e \in E : e$ is algebraic over $F \}$. Show that $A$ is a subfield of $E$ containing $F$.
First, clearly $A \subseteq E$. Also since $F$ is algebraic over itself, then $F \subseteq A$. To show $A$ is a subfield, we must show that every non-zero element of $A$ is a unit.
Let $\alpha \neq 0$ and $\alpha \in A$. As $F(\alpha)$ is a finite extension of $F$, $F(\alpha)$ is an algebraic of $F$. Since $\alpha^{-1} \in F(\alpha)$ $($because $F(\alpha)$ is a field$)$, then $\alpha^{-1}$ is algebraic over $F$. So $\alpha^{-1} \in A$. Then $\alpha$ is a unit in $A$. Thus, $A$ is a subfield of $E$.
Did I make any grave errors here?
EDIT:
Closure Under Addition and Multiplication
Let $a,b \in A$. Then consider the finite extension $F(a,b)$. Since $F(a,b)$ is finite over $F$, it is algebraic over $F$. Now, $a+b \in F(a,b)$ and hence $a+b$ is algebraic over $F$. Thus, $a+b \in A$. Similarly, $ab \in F(a,b)$ and so by the same reasoning $ab \in A$.

How about the other things, i.e. that if $a$ and $b$ are in $A$, then $a-b$ and $ab$ are in $A$?

You still have to show that it's closed under addition and multiplication.

@BrianMoehring Thanks. The typo has been fixed.

"Then consider the finite extension $F(a,b)$.  Since $F(a,b)$ is finite over $F$, it is algebraic over $F$" is a bit strong for this level of argument.  If the argument is valid for your case, then it's fine, but if it's not valid, that's where your problem is going to lie (I suppose it'll depend on the definitions).
